# Cancelling only the main task in an asyncio program

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.9

Normally, if a coroutine is started using the `asyncio.run(coroutine)` function, a keyboard interrupt (CTRL + C) or SIGINT will cancel all the pending tasks on the event loop. I'm looking for a way where only the main task (the one passed to `asyncio.run(coroutine)`) would be cancelled. The idea being that the main task will then orchestrate the cancellation of all the sub-tasks in whatever order it sees fit.

Consider an example:

```py
import asyncio


async def main():
    foo_task = asyncio.create_task(foo())
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print('main finished')
    finally:
        print('ensuring foo task is finished')
        await foo_task


async def foo():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('foo finished')


try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I want to change the code above so that if a keyboard interupt or SIGINT is sent in the middle of the execution, the `foo_task` would still be finished. It should print the following:

```sh
ensuring foo task is finished
foo finished
```

I don't want to use shielding (`asyncio.shield(coroutine)`) because I would like the main task to have full control over the order of cancellation/execution of its' sub-tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's a good idea, but on Unix-like operating systems you could achieve desired behavior with signal handlers.

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import tasks
import signal
from typing import Coroutine, Set

to_cancel: Set[Coroutine] = set()  # little workaround to detect the main task

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, cancel_main)
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, cancel_main)

    foo_task = asyncio.create_task(foo())

    try:
        print("main sleeping")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("main cancelled")
    finally:
        print('ensuring foo task is finished')
        await foo_task
        print('main finished')


async def foo():
    print("foo sleeping")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("foo finished")


def cancel_main():
    for task in tasks.all_tasks():
        # task.get_coro() for python >= 3.8 else task._coro
        if task.get_coro() in to_cancel and not task.cancelled():
            task.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    coro = main()
    to_cancel.add(coro)
    asyncio.run(coro)
```

Result

```
main sleeping
foo sleeping
^C
main cancelled
ensuring foo task is finished
foo finished
main finished
```